# What does this error mean in my GUI app and how to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a pythion gui that will require you to put your name in, your birthday, and your gender, and it will display what you you type in `Listbox`es. This is my code:

```
from cProfile import label
from cmath import e
from tkinter import*
from datetime import date
from tkinter import messagebox
one = Tk()
one.title("NICE")
one.state("zoomed")
today = date.today()

thr3e = StringVar
vowel_number = StringVar()
n = IntVar()


listed =[]

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Male")

def adi():
    a.insert(END, three.get())
def gen():
    if clicked.get() == "Male":
        b.insert(END, three.get())
    else:
        c.insert(END, three.get())
def age():
    d= int(birth_day.get())
    m=int(birth_month.get())
    y=int(birth_year.get())
    age = today.year-y-((today.month, today.day)<(m,d))
    d1.delete(0, END)                           
    for yo_mum in listed:
        d1.insert(END, yo_mum)
def v_count():
 s = (three.get)
 n=0

 for i in s:
    if i == 'a' or i == 'e'or i == 'A'or i == 'E':
        n=n+1
    elif i == 'i' or i == 'o'or i == 'u'or i == 'I'or i == 'O'or i == 'U':
        n = n+1

two = []
"Male",
"Female"



frame = Frame(one)
frame.pack(pady=5)

lf = Frame(frame)
lf.pack(pady=5)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Name")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

a = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
a.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Male")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

b = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Female")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

c = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
c.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Age")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

d1 = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
d1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

frame2 = Frame(one)
frame2.pack(pady=20)


three = Entry(frame2, font=("Futura", 30),textvariable=thr3e)
three.pack(pady=20)

lbal = Label(frame2, text = "Number of Vowels", font=("Futura", 25))
lbal.pack(pady = 2)

thr33 = Entry(frame2, font=("Futura", 30),textvariable=vowel_number)
thr33.pack(pady=20)


age1 = Frame(frame2)
age1.pack(pady=10)

lbf = Frame(age1)
lbf.pack()

Label(lbf, text="Birth Year", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=150)
Label(lbf, text="Birth Month", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(lbf, text="Birth Date", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=150)

yearvalue = StringVar()
monthvalue = StringVar()
dayvalue = StringVar()

birth_year = Entry(age1, textvariable=yearvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_year.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birth_month = Entry(age1, textvariable=monthvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_month.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birth_day = Entry(age1, textvariable=dayvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_day.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

drop = OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *two )
drop.pack(pady=10)   
add = Button(frame2, text="Submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age(), v_count()])
add.pack(pady = 10)




#LABEL/BUTTON

one.mainloop()
```

I'm also trying to add a function that tells me how many vowels are in your name, but the problem is that it keeps on giving me this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yashkaipa/from tkinter import *.py", line 143, in <module>
    drop = OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *two )
TypeError: OptionMenu.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
yashkaipa@Yashs-MacBook-Air ~ % ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you didn't pass all the required parameters to construct an `OpitonsMenu` widget. Here's some [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/optionmenu.html).

The problem appears to be because you didn't initialize the `two` list variable properly and it's empty. Change this:

```
two = []
"Male",
"Female"
```

to this

```
two = ["Male", "Female"]
```

and the `TypeError` will go away.

I also noticed that you're not initializing the `thr3e` variable properly either (you just haven't encountered the error yet).

Change:

```
thr3e = StringVar
```

to

```
thr3e = StringVar()
```

to *call* the `StringVar` class and create an instance.